# Markdown react render

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js, markdown

I am using react-markdown library to render text. I have an error when typing 3 backticks and it won't render: ```Text here.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VM18H.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hA3i8.png)

I have tried installing plugins like remark-gfm, react-syntax-highlighter, .... But the results still do not change.

Comment: Please re-read [how to ask a good question](/help/how-to-ask) and [edit] your post accordingly.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.